# Android Cloud Firestore efficient way to get few documents from collection

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is the most efficient way to get 3 documents (marked red) from firebase collection? One more obstacle for me is, that user document has auto-generated Id. The code below works but I think  is not efficient way to do it. If 'times' collection grows, retrieving whole collection while want only one or two documents doesn't make sense.
If there is no way to improve it, any suggestions of modifying my firestore structure to achieve the goal?

[image]

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("users")
        .whereEqualTo("userName", "tolek")
        .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        // task - retrieves entire user document with all fields and collections, what I don't want - want only document Id
        if (!task.getResult().getDocuments().isEmpty()) {
            db.collection("users")
                    .document(task.getResult().getDocuments().get(0).getId())
                    .collection("times")
                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (!task.getResult().getDocuments().isEmpty()) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult().getDocuments()) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Documents : " + snapshot.getId());
                            //here also I receive whole "times" collection but want only 3 documents
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "that user document has auto-generated Id"? Do you know the UID? Besides that? do you have the ID of those documents? 20210225, 20210226 and 20210227?

Comment: The ID of user document is randomly generated by Firebase. For documents  20210225, 20210226 and 20210227 I have IDs.

Comment: How can *"The ID of user document is randomly generated by Firebase"*? Why not use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) to always know the UID?

Comment: These users are added by main, authenticated user and don't need to do authentication. The auto-generated ID of document I meant Firestore - if don't set ID by creating, comes automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the loading of the 3 `times` documents, you can [use an `in` query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any):

```
CollectionReference timesRef =  db.collection("users")
                    .document(task.getResult().getDocuments().get(0).getId())
                    .collection("times");

timesRef.whereIn(FieldPath.documentId(), Arrays.asList("20210225", "20210226", "20210227"));
```

This works for up to 10 values. If you have more than 10 IDs, you'll need to fire more than one query.

Comment: Works fine and doesn't load entire collection. Thanks!